# How to add image into TextView

Tags: android, listview, android-listview, arraylist

I have created a table that contains information on the certain individual headings. However, I am wondering how to input static image into the individual cells within a column.

Code that is used to create specific column that is inclusive of the images in each cell:

```
TextView label_col_1_datatab3 = new TextView(this);
label_col_1_datatab3.setId(200+cnt); 
label_col_1_datatab3.addTouchables(chair_list +count);  //THERE IS AN ERROR FOR THIS LINE WHERE I AM TRYING TO INPUT AN ARRAY OF IMAGES.
label_col_1_datatab3.setText(product_showcase_list[cnt]);
label_col_1_datatab3.setTextColor(Color.BLACK);
label_col_1_datatab3.setPadding(100, 50, 100, 50);
row_tab3.addView(label_col_1_datatab3);
```

Code for chair_list:

```
ArrayList<View> chair_list = new ArrayList {

        R.drawable.banana_chair, 
        R.drawable.circular_chair,
        R.drawable.purplechair
 };
```

XML:

```
             <TableRow
                 android:id="@+id/table_Row1"
                 android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                 android:layout_height="wrap_content">
                                <ListView
                                    android:id="@+id/list_image"
                                    android:layout_width="80dip"
                                    android:layout_height="80dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/banana_chair"/>
                                <ListView
                                    android:id="@+id/list_image2"
                                    android:layout_width="80dip"
                                    android:layout_height="80dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/circular_chair"/>
                                <ListView
                                    android:id="@+id/list_image3"
                                    android:layout_width="80dip"
                                    android:layout_height="80dip"
                                    android:src="@drawable/purplechair"/>
             </TableRow>
```

Comment: try drawableright or drawabletop or drawableleft or drawableleft in your textview in XML ??

Comment: @Dhina  what do you mean?? I have updated with the XML code

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try the code snippet below :

```
TextView label_col_1_datatab3 = new TextView(this);
label_col_1_datatab3 .setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0);
```

Comment: but that param is only for one drawable icon?? what if i have multiple?

Comment: @ErnestLee Only one drawable, can be drawn below/to the end,left,right/start/above the text. check : http://developer.android.com/reference/android/widget/TextView.html#setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(int, int, int, int)

Comment: understood, but how about if I need to add different images in different cells?

Comment: @ErnestLee, you are talking about cells of TableLayout ?

Comment: Yeaps!! Cause "setCompoundDrawablesWithIntrinsicBounds(R.drawable.icon, 0, 0, 0)" only calls the drawable resource to only one cell within the table layout, but what if I need multiple images to different cells? BTW, thanks, that code itself works fine.

Comment: Np, @ErnestLee check out this tutorial : http://programmerguru.com/android-tutorial/android-tablelayout-example/#table_layout. Btw if my response answer your question don't forget to mark it as accepted.